# Main thread crash after AsyncTask is finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I im using AsyncTask to get string from my server.

My problem is that after AsyncTask is finished my main thread is crashes and the app is

loading the previous window.

The strange thing is that im not getting any error code in my logcat.

Thank for helping.

This is my code and logcat:

```
07-12 00:58:51.162: I/ActivityManager(1834): START u0 {cmp=com.tomer.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage (has extras)} from pid 28701
07-12 00:58:51.182: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): do_aic3254_control device: 1 mode: 0 record: 0
07-12 00:58:51.182: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): aic3254_ioctl: new_aic_rxmode 13 cur_aic_rx 29
07-12 00:58:51.182: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): aic3254_ioctl()
07-12 00:58:51.182: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): aic3254_ioctl: try ioctl 0x40047313 with arg 13
07-12 00:58:51.192: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): aic3254_ioctl: new_aic_txmode 29 cur_aic_tx 29
07-12 00:58:51.192: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): value of device and enable is 6 1 ALSA dev id:6
07-12 00:58:51.232: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): updateACDB: (11, 6, 0, 607) 
07-12 00:58:51.232: I/HTC Acoustic(1489): update ACDB id: (tx, rx, tx_acdb, rx_acdb) = (11, 6, 0, 607)
07-12 00:58:51.232: D/AudioHardwareMSM7X30(1489): msm_route_stream(PCM_PLAY,5,6,1)
07-12 00:58:51.652: I/ActivityManager(1834): Displayed com.tomer.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage: +474ms
07-12 00:58:52.033: W/InputMethodManagerService(1834): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41948370 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@415ff880
```

code:

```
   class GetKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddWorkOutPage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("loading...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = null;
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exercise", exercise));

                json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_key,"GET", params);

                try {
                    base64EncodedPublicKey = json.getString("key");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product

                    //Log.d("ok", json.toString());
                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you telling `onPostExecute()` to accept a `String` but returning `null` from `doInBackground()`?

Comment: How do you know that you are crashing? Is there an exception in stacktrace or any other message that indicates crashing?

Comment: I can remove the string, you think that thats was is casuing the problem?  I know it crashing because i see it on my device

Comment: I don't know but see my answer and see if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two potential problems:

1. As in my comment, you are telling `onPostExecute()` to accept a `String` but returning `null` in `doInBackground()`. I'm not sure this would cause the problem but I've never tried. If you don't want to return anything you can change to

   protected void onPostExecute(Void response)

and change your class declaration to

```
 class GetKey extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
```

assuming you are passing a `String` in `execute()` when you call the task

2 You are calling `finish()` in `doInBackground()` but `AsyncTask` doesn't have a finish() method so you are either finishing your `Activity` or getting error there.

Comment: Thank you. I removed finish and change to AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> and it working

Comment: Btw the null in the return was not the problem (but it was useless). :)

Comment: @Enrichman I didn't think it would cause the crash but thought I might as well suggest removing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calling finish() from your doInBackground() method, so you're modifying in some way your context and getting an exception.

Instead of a String return the Integer from the result and finish() your Activity in the onPostExecute().

```
  class GetKey extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer> {
    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddWorkOutPage.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected Integer doInBackground(String... args) {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = null;
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exercise", exercise));

        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_get_key,"GET", params);

        try {
            base64EncodedPublicKey = json.getString("key");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // check for success tag
        int success = 0;
        try {
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);                
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return success;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer success) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (success == 1) {
           // successfully created product
           //Log.d("ok", json.toString());
           // closing this screen
           finish();
        } else {
           // failed to create product
        }
    }

}
```